# Draw a circle menu in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to draw a circle menu as seen in the attached image below, however I am new to Flutter and I have no idea where to start with something like this.

I will only have 8 peaces instead of 12 as seen in the image, and they will all be links, each link going to a different section of the app.

In the centre grey area, we will have short text

[image]

Comment: https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-radial-menu-staggered-animations/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I hope it will give something to start.**

[image]

**Steps:**

1. Draw the svg via something like [Figma](https://www.figma.com)
2. Use [path_parsing](https://pub.dev/packages/path_parsing) package to create flutter `Path` from `svg path`
3. Create `ShapeDecoration` or `ClipPath`, I've choose `ClipPath`, but with `ShapeDecoration` you can add the shadows.
4. Use `Matrix4` for `Path` or `Transform.rotate` to rotate. I've choose `Transform.rotate twice it's was faster but using [Path.transform](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/transform.html) is much cleaner approach.
5. Calculate the place of each petal of the menu, using sine and cosine of angle.
6. Tune everything a bit.

**Happy coding! Enjoy!**

p.s. It could be better if we do solution without specific number of pieces.

**the sample code:**

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const double degrees2Radians = math.pi / 180.0;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final items = [
    ButtonData(title: 'one', onTap: () => print('1')),
    ButtonData(title: 'two', onTap: () => print('2')),
    ButtonData(title: 'three', onTap: () => print('3')),
    ButtonData(title: 'four', onTap: () => print('4')),
    ButtonData(title: 'five', onTap: () => print('5')),
    ButtonData(title: 'six', onTap: () => print('6')),
    ButtonData(title: 'seven', onTap: () => print('7')),
    ButtonData(title: 'eight', onTap: () => print('8')),
    ButtonData(onTap: () => print('center')),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 300,
      width: 300,
      child: Stack(
        children: items
            .asMap()
            .map((index, buttonData) {
              if (index < 8) {
                var degree = 360 / 8 * index;
                var radian = degree * degrees2Radians;
                return MapEntry(
                  index,
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment(
                      math.sin(radian),
                      math.cos(radian),
                    ),
                    child: Transform.rotate(
                      angle: -radian,
                      child: MenuPetal(angle: -radian, buttonData: buttonData),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
              return MapEntry(
                index,
                _centerButton(buttonData),
              );
            })
            .values
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _centerButton(ButtonData buttonData) {
    return Center(
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: buttonData.onTap,
          child: Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.black38,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ButtonData {
  final String? title;
  final void Function()? onTap;

  ButtonData({this.title, this.onTap});
}

class MenuPetal extends StatelessWidget {
  const MenuPetal({
    super.key,
    required this.angle,
    required this.buttonData,
  });

  final double angle;
  final ButtonData buttonData;
  final double factor = 0.38;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FractionallySizedBox(
      heightFactor: factor,
      widthFactor: factor,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: buttonData.onTap,
        child: ClipPath(
          clipper: MyCustomClipper(),
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                image:
                    NetworkImage('https://source.unsplash.com/featured/?white'),
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: -angle,
                child: Text(buttonData.title ?? ""),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var x = size.width / 100 * 0.802;
    var y = size.height / 100;
    var path = Path()
      ..moveTo(39.4 * x, 6.1 * y)
      ..cubicTo(43.2 * x, -1.8 * y, 57.1 * x, -1.8 * y, 60.9 * x, 6.1 * y)
      ..lineTo(99.1 * x, 84.1 * y)
      ..cubicTo(102.1 * x, 90.2 * y, 99.1 * x, 93.9 * y, 92.0 * x, 95.6 * y)
      ..cubicTo(67.4 * x, 101.7 * y, 36.9 * x, 101.7 * y, 9.2 * x, 95.6 * y)
      ..cubicTo(1.2 * x, 93.8 * y, -1.3 * x, 88.7 * y, 1.2 * x, 84.1 * y)
      ..lineTo(39.4 * x, 6.1 * y);

    return path.shift(Offset(12, 0));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```