# Flutter Radial Select Menu (Pie Menu) Implementation

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I would like to create a widget commonly found in many games for selecting different options from a radial menu.

The widget should have a button in the middle which you drag to one part of a surrounding circle-outline to select one option.

One example is the spotting menu in Apex Legends.
[image]

How would you go about it?
I am pretty new to flutter.
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I've created something similar but this is exactly what i'm looking for. Any progress?

Comment: you can maybe finesse one of these solutions to your needs, not sure though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63623345/draw-a-circle-menu-in-flutter
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483259/implementing-circular-context-menu-in-flutter