# Implementing circular context menu in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, contextmenu

I have already searched for circular menu packages for flutter and all of them have fabs arranged radially. I want the UI such that wherever the user taps(onhold) a circular menu will popup with buttons divided in sectors.

[image]

Comment: Your options are: find a package that already does this, or make it yourself.

Comment: @Abion47 , I couldn't find a package to do this and second I am not proficient enough to do this.If you have found any  study material for advanced flutter, kindly share it .

Comment: Questions asking for tutorials or other such learning material are off-topic for SO. Detailed walkthroughs on how to make radial controls are just a Google search away. Now if you start implementing a radial control and get stuck on something specific, you may come back and ask a question about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick playground for such a Radial Context Menu.

It uses the concepts of State Management, Providers, Overlays...

I tried to keep it under 300 lines of code.

[image]

## Structure of the project:

### Domain Layer

For the purpose of this demo, I used `Boxes` defined by their `id`, `name` and `color`.

The Radial Menu is defined by a `MenuConfig` and `MenuActions`

### State Management Layer

For the boxes, I used a `boxesProvider` providing a list of boxes and the possibility to update their `color`.

For the menu, I defined a `menuProvider` as a `StateNotifierProvider.family` as well as a ScopedProvider for the current item on which my Radial Menu is applied.

### Presentation Layer

The structure of the Widget Tree is as follows:

```
Providercope
> MaterialApp
  > HomePage
    > Scaffold
      > GridView
        > BoxWidget
          > ProviderScope [contextIdProvider.overrideWithValue(box.id)]
            > ContextMenuDetector
```

The `ContextMenuDetector` is a `GestureDetector` that create the `RadialMenu` inside an `OverlayEntry` and manages the menu user experience thanks to `olLongPressStart`, `olLongPressMoveUpdate`, and `olLongPressUp`

I let you discover the full source code:

### Full source code:

```dart
import 'dart:math' show pi, cos, sin;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

part '66483259.radial_menu.freezed.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: 'Radial Menu Demo',
    home: HomePage(),
  )));
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final boxes = useProvider(boxesProvider.state);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Radial Menu Demo')),
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        children: boxes.map((box) => BoxWidget(box: box)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BoxWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Box box;

  const BoxWidget({Key key, this.box}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ProviderScope(
      overrides: [contextIdProvider.overrideWithValue(box.id)],
      child: ContextMenuDetector(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: box.color,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black87, width: 2.0),
          ),
          child: Text(box.name),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ContextMenuDetector extends HookWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const ContextMenuDetector({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final contextId = useProvider(contextIdProvider);
    final _menuConfig = useProvider(menuProvider(contextId).state);
    final _offsetCorrection = useState(Offset.zero);
    final _overlayEntry = useState<OverlayEntry>(null);

    OverlayEntry _createMenu({Offset offset}) => OverlayEntry(
          builder: (BuildContext overlayContext) {
            return ProviderScope(
              overrides: [contextIdProvider.overrideWithValue(contextId)],
              child: Positioned(
                left: offset.dx - kMenuRadius,
                top: offset.dy - kMenuRadius,
                child: RadialMenu(),
              ),
            );
          },
        );

    void _showMenu({Offset offset}) {
      _overlayEntry.value = _createMenu(offset: offset);
      Overlay.of(context).insert(_overlayEntry.value);
    }

    void _hideMenu() {
      _overlayEntry.value?.remove();
    }

    return GestureDetector(
      onLongPressStart: (details) {
        final menuOffset = Offset(
          details.globalPosition.dx.clamp(
              kMenuRadius, MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - kMenuRadius),
          details.globalPosition.dy.clamp(
              kMenuRadius, MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - kMenuRadius),
        );
        _offsetCorrection.value = details.globalPosition - menuOffset;
        _showMenu(offset: menuOffset);
      },
      onLongPressMoveUpdate: (details) {
        final offset = details.localOffsetFromOrigin + _offsetCorrection.value;
        if (offset.distance <= kMenuRadius) {
          final sextant =
              (((offset.direction / pi + 2 + 1 / 6) % 2) * 3).floor();
          if (sextant < 4) {
            context.read(menuProvider(contextId)).selectAction(sextant);
            return;
          }
        }
        context.read(menuProvider(contextId)).selectAction(-1);
      },
      onLongPressUp: () {
        if (_menuConfig.selectedAction >= 0) {
          _menuConfig.currentAction?.callback?.call(context, contextId);
        }
        _hideMenu();
      },
      child: child,
    );
  }
}

class RadialMenu extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final contextId = useProvider(contextIdProvider);
    final config = useProvider(menuProvider(contextId).state);
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Container(
        width: 2 * kMenuRadius,
        height: 2 * kMenuRadius,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey.shade200,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: RadialMenuPainter(config: config),
          size: Size(2 * kMenuRadius, 2 * kMenuRadius),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: .4 * kMenuRadius,
                left: .5 * kMenuRadius,
                right: .5 * kMenuRadius,
                child: Text('Menu $contextId', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
              ),
              ...config.actions.asMap().entries.map(
                (action) {
                  final angle = pi * action.key / 3;
                  return Positioned(
                    left: kMenuRadius * (.6 + .5 * cos(angle)),
                    top: kMenuRadius * (.6 + .5 * sin(angle)),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: .8 * kMenuRadius,
                      height: .8 * kMenuRadius,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(action.value.label,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0)),
                          Icon(action.value.iconData, size: 16.0),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RadialMenuPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final MenuConfig config;

  RadialMenuPainter({this.config});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = config.color
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = size.shortestSide * .1;
    canvas.drawCircle(
        Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2), size.shortestSide / 2, paint);
    config.actions.asMap().entries.forEach((action) {
      Paint paint = Paint()
        ..color = action.key == config.selectedAction
            ? action.value.color
            : action.value.color.withOpacity(.4)
        ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
      Path path = Path()
        ..moveTo(size.width / 2, size.height / 2)
        ..arcTo(
            Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * .1, size.height * .1, size.width * .8,
                size.height * .8),
            pi * (action.key / 3 - 1 / 6),
            pi / 3,
            false)
        ..close();
      canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    });
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant RadialMenuPainter oldDelegate) =>
      oldDelegate.config.selectedAction != config.selectedAction;
}

final boxesProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<BoxesNotifier>((ref) => BoxesNotifier(24));

class BoxesNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Box>> {
  BoxesNotifier(int nbBoxes)
      : super(
          List.generate(
            nbBoxes,
            (index) => Box(id: index, name: 'Box $index', color: Colors.white),
          ),
        );

  updateBoxColor(int id, Color color) {
    state = [...state]..[id] = state[id].copyWith(color: color);
  }
}

@freezed
abstract class Box with _$Box {
  const factory Box({int id, String name, Color color}) = _Box;
}

final contextIdProvider =
    ScopedProvider<int>((ref) => throw UnimplementedError());

final menuProvider = StateNotifierProvider.family<MenuNotifier, int>(
    (ref, id) => MenuNotifier(menuConfig));

class MenuNotifier extends StateNotifier<MenuConfig> {
  MenuNotifier(MenuConfig state) : super(state);

  void selectAction(int index) {
    state = state.copyWith(selectedAction: index);
  }
}

@freezed
abstract class MenuConfig implements _$MenuConfig {
  const factory MenuConfig({
    @Default(Colors.white) Color color,
    @Default([]) List<MenuAction> actions,
    int selectedAction,
  }) = _RadialMenuConfig;
  const MenuConfig._();

  MenuAction get currentAction => actions[selectedAction];
}

@freezed
abstract class MenuAction with _$MenuAction {
  const factory MenuAction(
      {String label,
      IconData iconData,
      void Function(BuildContext, int id) callback,
      Color color}) = _MenuAction;
}

final menuConfig = MenuConfig(
  color: Colors.lightBlue.shade200,
  actions: [
    MenuAction(
      label: 'Cut',
      iconData: Icons.cut,
      color: Colors.red.shade200,
      callback: (context, id) =>
          context.read(boxesProvider).updateBoxColor(id, Colors.red.shade200),
    ),
    MenuAction(
      label: 'Copy',
      iconData: Icons.copy,
      color: Colors.green.shade200,
      callback: (context, id) =>
          context.read(boxesProvider).updateBoxColor(id, Colors.green.shade200),
    ),
    MenuAction(
      label: 'Paste',
      iconData: Icons.paste,
      color: Colors.blue.shade200,
      callback: (context, id) =>
          context.read(boxesProvider).updateBoxColor(id, Colors.blue.shade200),
    ),
    MenuAction(
      label: 'Undo',
      iconData: Icons.undo,
      color: Colors.indigo.shade200,
      callback: (context, id) => context
          .read(boxesProvider)
          .updateBoxColor(id, Colors.indigo.shade200),
    ),
  ],
);

const double kMenuRadius = 100.0;
```

### Package Dependencies

- [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) ([Flutter Hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) flavor) for State Management
- [Freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) for Domain classes immutability

Comment: Can you explain the math a little please? Trying to get the segments to render in order and this might be the way I'm handling focus traverse, but just in case, curious about the math (even if basic).

Answer (score -1):

For apps nowadays, it is a common UX practice to **radially pop-up more buttons** for extra actions that the user can perform.

This, however, is useful for presenting multiple actions to the user, but is **not useful** in cases where you want the user to **perform a primary action**.

Still, if your case fits the need, be sure to check out [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhQI-ysRyrk) from Jeff @firehsip.io

Comment: Don't post answers that are just links. The answer becomes useless if the link is ever taken down.

Comment: Sure. But I don't think this is the case with it.

Comment: Youtube videos get taken down or changed to private all the time. Your answer is not protected in that regard.

Comment: They don't take videos down for fun bro, only if there is something controversial or copyrighted, which is not the case here.

Comment: The video can also be taken down by the user at any time for any reason, or the video could be region locked. Look, this debate is purely academic at this point and I'm not interested in arguing with you further. You are far from the first person to post a link to a YouTube video, and it's not that uncommon to find where the video is no longer available. It's long been SO policy that answers that just consist of links elsewhere are poor quality because, no matter your rationale for defense, NO link is guaranteed to be up forever. An answer that isn't self-contained isn't a good answer, period.